# IBM RIT - map current dateTime into request

Tags: unit-testing, datetime, testing, integration-testing

Is there a function to map the current dateTime into a test request message in IBM RIT?

I found the "now" function in the [online help](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSBLQQ_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.rit.ref.doc/topics/c_ritref_other_functions.html) but that doesn't work, the provider receives basically the string '*now("2016-10-10")*'

If that's possible, I would like also to know which function does a datetimediff.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

There is an in built function you can use

```
tags["SYSTEM/CURRENT_TIME"]
```

and yoiu can use the substring function to split it into whatever you want. for example:

```
tt = tags["SYSTEM/CURRENT_TIME"]

tthh = tt.substring(0,2) ******************this returns hour of the day

ttmm = tt.substring(3,5) ******************this returns minutes

ttss = tt.substring(6,8) ******************this returns seconds

ttNew = tthh+ttmm+ttss
```

You can also do the same for the date using the inbuilt function

```
tt = tags["SYSTEM/CURRENT_DATE"]
```